# How to add a Group inside another group in AEM?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am trying to add a group as a member to another group in AEM using workflow, but it is not adding and moreover it is not throwing any error.

```
Map<String, Object> subServiceParameters = new HashMap<>();
subServiceParameters.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, GlobalConstants.SERVICE_USER_MAPPER_NAME);
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(subServiceParameters);

UserManager userManager = workflowSession.adaptTo(ResourceResolver.class).adaptTo(UserManager.class);
Group group = (Group) userManager.getAuthorizable("COMPANY_ADMINISTRATORS");
group.addMember(userManager.getAuthorizable("COMPANY_TAG_ADMINISTRATORS"));
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
session.save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using workflowsession to create usermanager object whereas i was saving the jcr session, because of this my code was not working. Please use the below line for user manager rest all working fine.

```
UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
```